# Count Text values, but not repeats

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To be honest, I don't even know what I am asking, but I think it should be possible. I am trying to count the number of groupings for a certain person given a specific condition (T/F).

For example, Let's assume these are all true

```
Orange   Alpha
Orange   Alpha
Black    Beta
Black    Beta
Blue     Beta
Blue     Beta
Blue     Beta
Green    Delta
Green    Alpha
```

I am trying to create a table that will say Beta: 2, Alpha 2, and Delta 1. Then vice versa I need something that will say Orange 1, Black 1, Blue 1, Green 2. Essentially count the number of names within in a color.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know VBA, but would love to learn... Would like to do it in cells, but I don't even think that is possible. Also I didn't put the VBA tag.

Comment: It is the for-loop tag that indicates VBA as for-loop is part of VBA not formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formula you will need to use Array formulas:

For the Alpha column:

```
=SUM(IF($B$1:$B$9=D1,1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,$A$1:$A$9,$B$1:$B$9,D1)))
```

For the Color column:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$9=G1,1/COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$9,$B$1:$B$9,$A$1:$A$9,G1)))
```

As these are array formulas they need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter on exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Could you explain what is happening though? I get the SUM and logic of the first part of the if, but what is with the 1/COUNTIFS part?

Comment: It makes a fraction of the countif.  So for the ALPHA it ends up summing `1/2 + 1/2` for the Orange and `1/1` for the Green.  This gives the desired 2.  So the first part of the Countifs looks at each part of the other column and counts the number of each item that satisfies the whole and divides 1 by that number then adds them to get 1 for each group. @JackArmstrong